# GCP App Engine Access to GCloud Storage without 'sharing publicly'

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I would like to know how to grant a Google Cloud Platform App Engine project permissions to serve content from Google Cloud Storage without setting the Google Cloud Storage bucket permissions to ‘share publicly'.

My App engine project is running Node JS. Uses Passport-SAML authentication to authenticate users before allowing them to view content, hence I do not want to set access on an individual user level via IAM. Images and videos are currently served from within a private folder of my app, which is only accessible once users are authenticated. I wish to move these assets to Google Cloud Storage and allow the app to read the files, whist not providing global access. How should I go about doing this? I failed to find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket):

> By default, when you create a bucket for your project, **your app has
>   all the permissions required to read and write to it**.

Whenever you create an App Engine application, there is a default bucket that comes with the following perks:

- 5GB of free storage.
- Free quota for Cloud Storage I/O operations

By default it is created automatically with your application, but in any case you can follow the same link I shared previously in other to create the bucket. Should you need more than those 5GB of free storage, you can make it a paid bucket and you will only be charged for the storage that surpasses the first 5 GB.

Then, you can make use of the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) for Node.js and have a look at some nice samples ([general samples here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.5.x/#samples) or even [specific operations over files here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js))  for working with the files inside your bucket.

---

***UPDATE:***

Here there is a small working example on how to use the Cloud Storage client libraries to retrieve images from your private bucket without making them public, by means of authenticating requests. It works in a Cloud Function, so you should have no issues in reproducing the same behavior in App Engine. It does not perform exactly what you need, as it displays the image in the bucket alone, without any integration inside an HTML file, but you should be able to build something from that (I am not too used to work with Node.js, unfortunately).

I hope this can be of some help too.

```
'use strict';

const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

exports.imageServer = function imageSender(req, res) {
  let file = gcs.bucket('<YOUR_BUCKET>').file('<YOUR_IMAGE>');
  let readStream = file.createReadStream();

  res.setHeader("content-type", "image/jpeg");
  readStream.pipe(res);
};
```

Comment: I assume that it is not as simple as my app can serving a page with an image tag like <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/imagename.jpg”> within static html. I assume I must do something like generating a signed URL (as njLT suggests) with Google Cloud client library and then dynamically use that url in my page?

Comment: I don't think signed URLs are the solution to your problem, because they make the content public to everyone having the URL, so it is similar to making the content public (but you can add an expiration date). Signed URLs are thought to give access to Cloud Storage resources without requiring a Google account but still controlling access.

Comment: I see your point. Is there an example of a best practice way of displaying a non-public image hosted on google cloud within an app-engine app?

Comment: After some more research it seems that adding a service account key might be the way forward: https://medium.com/@iwozzy/easily-host-images-with-node-and-google-cloud-storage-29fb14e2cdb8

Comment: The last link you shared is just making images public in order to serve them, which is what you did not want in the first case. After some investigation, I have found that both PHP and Python App Engine libraries offer a really interesting function that returns a public URL that is not guessable, which could fit your requirements better ( [*get_serving_url*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/#get-serving-url) ). However this is not available in the Node.js API. Everything I can find regarding how to serve images from a Node application involves making files public.

Comment: So at the moment it does not seem like there is a way to serve images from Cloud Storage to a Node.js application without making them explicitly public. The API I shared with you has a function suitable for downloading images, (not serving them), so maybe you can finally stick to using signed URLs, as they make the files available to anyone having the URL, but its  structure is more difficult to guess than the normal public Storage links. If that is your final choice, [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js#L286) you have the function you will need.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It is not exactly what you need, but maybe you can build something interesting from that base. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program
I can't seem to find the API doc for nodejs (google is really messing around with their doc urls). Here's some sample code:

```
bucket.upload(filename, options, function(err, file, apiResponse) {
var mil = Date.now()+60000;
var config = {
  action: 'read',
  expires: mil
};

file.getSignedUrl(config, function(err, url) {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(url);
});
```